# ajax response on another domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have specific scenario to work with, It will be interesting and helpful to many developers, I have js file and a php file, In js file i code AJAX, using http request that send parameters to php file and get a response.

Now I have 2 domains

**on 1st Domain**

I have Database, Store some html codes, Can create AJAX to get data from database to a Javascript file.

**on 2nd Domain**

I want to display HTML codes from the 1st domain database using Javascript or AJAX

Is there any way to do this kind of trick?

Comment: Is there any clear cut example of its use ? I dont have full access to 2nd domain ftp to upload any file there, I just place some code these to display data there ?

Comment: Only response that I get is Blank page with status == 0 not 200

Answer (score 0):

You need use [CORS technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) also look at [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

**Wikipedia source:**

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows many resources (e.g., fonts, JavaScript, etc.) on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain the resource originated from. In particular, JavaScript's [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) calls can use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) mechanism. Such "cross-domain" requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same origin security policy. CORS defines a way in which the browser and the server can interact to determine whether or not to allow the cross-origin request. It is more useful than only allowing same-origin requests, but it is more secure than simply allowing all such cross-origin requests.

**Simple Example:**

To initiate a cross-origin request, a browser sends the request with an Origin HTTP header. The value of this header is the domain that served the page. For example, suppose a page from http://www.example-social-network.com attempts to access a user's data in online-personal-calendar.com. If the user's browser implements CORS, the following request header would be sent to online-personal-calendar.com:

```
Origin: http://www.example-social-network.com
```

If online-personal-calendar.com allows the request, it sends an Access-Control-Allow-Origin (ACAO) header in its response. The value of the header indicates what origin sites are allowed. For example, a response to the previous request could contain the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example-social-network.com
```

If the server does not allow the cross-origin request, the browser will deliver an error to example-social-network.com page instead of the online-personal-calendar.com response.

To allow access from all domains, a server can send the following response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

**Browser support:**

CORS is supported by all browsers based on the following layout engines:

1. Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5, SeaMonkey 2.0, Camino 2.1) and above.
2. WebKit (Initial revision uncertain, Safari 4 and above, Google Chrome 3 and above, possibly earlier)
3. MSHTML/Trident 6.0 (Internet Explorer 10) has native support. MSHTML/Trident 4.0 & 5.0 (Internet Explorer 8 & 9) provide partial support via the [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object.
4. Presto-based browsers (Opera) implement CORS as of Opera 12.00 and Opera Mobile 12, but not Opera Mini.

The following browsers are also noteworthy in their lack of CORS support:
 1. Camino does not implement CORS in the 2.0.x release series because these versions are based on Gecko 1.9.0.
 2. As of version 0.10.2, Arora exposes WebKit's CORS-related APIs, but attempted cross-origin requests will fail.

Comment: I am looking at this , http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/cross-domain-ajax/ . But i am confused , May I need to put some sort of files to 2nd domain or I just need to put all files on 1st domain and then Use only Js code on 2nd domain ? Is there a clear cut example

Comment: Actually, you need js file on page, which will request other domain for data, script file you can locate anywhere, and attach by script tag with src specified attribute

Comment: I have edited the question with code, please check and give me advice on that

Comment: You can view examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper script on server side to make the call to the second domain and then you just call your script.